# Transforming XML to http URI-template

Tags: rest, http, soap, uri, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB to translate incoming SOAP payload onto outbound REST api. We are currently using XPath to set parameters and use them to craft http endpoint (uri-template). This approach works with few parameters but as number of parameters increases, the XML code is hard to manage and more error prone.

Any suggestion on best practice to to extract XML element/attribute values and populate REST URL (uri-template)?

Comment: Could you please post that kind of a problematic uri-template with lots of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you can design the your REST Api in proper way.
In the your REST Api, you can design resource methods with less number of URL parameters(to select the resource) and other parameters you can send via the message payload (via request body)